# VS Code ignoring break points when debugging typescript program

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have hello world program on typescript:

```
function say(msg: string) {
    alert(msg);
    for (let i:number=0;i<10;i++)
        document.write(i+"<br/>");
}
var msg:string="hello typescript world!";
say(msg);
```

this code is inside src folder. When I run compiler (tsc) it successfully generates *.js and *.map files and put them inside src folder.Also there is index.html in the root of the project

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/hello.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run debug session in chrome my breakpoints are ignored with the message

> Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map
>   problem?)

In the web server logs I can see following line:

> "GET /src/hello.js.map" "undefined"

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap":true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug in Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workSpaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE:
When trying to set breakpoint with chrome debugging tool it does stop on breakpoint but doesn't show my js/ts code:
breakpoint added
[image: breakpoint added]

breakpoint reached
[image: breakpoint reached]

Comment: What happens if you try to browse to the `/src/hello.js.map` file in chrome? 404 not found?

Comment: Did you install the chrome debug extension in VS Code?

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes I've installed debug extension

Comment: @Arg0n What do you mean by `browse in chrome`?

Comment: In the address field: go to `http://localhost:8080/src/hello.js.map`, does the file show as text, or does it not return the file at all? Might be a file type issue with your server.

Comment: yes it shows *.map file content

Comment: Can you debug the **TypeScript** in Chrome built in debugger?

Comment: @Arg0n Chrome says source map detected but if I try to set breakpoint chrome sets breakpoint in the ts file and when execution reaches breakpoint it stops and opens hello.ts tab with no code.See initial post updated

Comment: Then there might be a problem with the `.map` file? Have you checked it/tried retranspiling? Which version of `tsc` are you using?

Comment: I removed *.js and *.map files and ran tsc again - same result.My tsc version is 2.5.2.I think map file is ok since chrome does recognize breakpoint but it can't show the code where it stop since breakpoint is in ts file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with VS code.I started new project with exactly the same launch.json,tsconfig.json and source code and its debugging ok in chrome!Then I copied everything into my initial project and now its debugging ok too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings (click "F1") and disable the option "Enable Javascript source maps".